# How to filter out more than one object from an array using multiple text string condition

Tags: javascript, filtering, nightwatch.js

I'm trying to write a test and I have an array of objects which look something like this:

```
menuOfProducts: [ 
  { text: 'Product One',
    selector: '#product-one #productone',
    path: 'productone' },
  { text: 'Product Two',
    selector: '#product-two #producttwo',
    path: 'shop/catalog/producttwo' },
  { text: 'Product Three',
    selector: '#product-three #productthree',
    path: 'shop/catalog/productthree' },
  { text: 'Product Four',
    selector: '#product-four #productfour',
    path: 'shop/catalog/productfour' },
  { text: 'Product Five',
    selector: '#product-five #productfive',
    path: 'shop/catalog/productfive' }
]
```

What I would like to do is filter out a couple of the objects and return the rest.

So far I have tried to use .filter() to filter out one of the objects which works fine. However it may be required to filter out more than one product by text. This is what I have now:

```
if (environment === 'test') {
  menuOfProducts = menuOfProducts.filter(function (option) {
    return option.text !== 'Product Two';
  });
}
```

And using this filter I get the correct array returned minus "Product Two":

```
[ 
  { text: 'Product One',
    selector: '#product-one #productone',
    path: 'productone' },
  { text: 'Product Three',
    selector: '#product-three #productthree',
    path: 'shop/catalog/productthree' },
  { text: 'Product Four',
    selector: '#product-four #productfour',
    path: 'shop/catalog/productfour' },
  { text: 'Product Five',
    selector: '#product-five #productfive',
    path: 'shop/catalog/productfive' }
]
```

But as mentioned above I would like to now filter multiple objects out by text. And was wondering how can I approach this? I have tried passing in another condition in the filter like this:

```
if (environment === 'test') {
  menuOfProducts = menuOfProducts.filter(function (option) {
    return option.text !== 'Product Two' || 'Product Three';
  });
}
```

But then I get the array returned with ALL object and nothing is filtered out. Any help would be greatly received. Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting all the values returned because `'Product Three'` is a [`truthy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value

Use the [Logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) operator like this:

```
if (environment === 'test') {
  menuOfProducts = menuOfProducts.filter(function (option) {
    return option.text !== 'Product Two' && option.text !== 'Product Three';
  });
}
```

If you have a multiple `option.text` to `filter`, you could create an array of those values and use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes):

```
if (environment === 'test') {
  menuOfProducts = menuOfProducts.filter(function(option) {
    return !['Product Two', 'Product Three'].includes(option.text);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks Adiga. This is a good solution I was looking for because it is very likely that a few more text will need to be filtered so having the array which holds the product text is perfect. Thanks so much for your time to reply

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this:

```
if (environment === 'test') {
  menuOfProducts = menuOfProducts.filter(function (option) {
    return option.text !== 'Product Two' && option.text !== 'Product Three';
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply Arpit. But I do really like Adiga's solution with the array of values and using .every() to filter out each value in the array of words. So have used that. Thanks again for the time to reply

Answer (score 0):

You are using the logic operators wrong. You use it in a way that a real person might understand, but a computer has to be treated differently.

Your logic term: `option.text !== 'Product Two' || 'Product Three';`
I shorten this to `A !== B || C`
The [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence) makes that equivalent to this: `(A !== B) || C`
This translates to 'A not equal to B else C'
So if `A !== B` is true, the whole term has the value of true (because `true || anything` is always `true`). But if `A !== B` is false, the whole term will evaluated to `V` (because `false || anything` is always `anything`)
So you will either have the value `true` of `C`, `C` is the string `'Product Three'` which is a [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) value.
In the end your full term `option.text !== 'Product Two' || 'Product Three'` will always be true, thus nothing is filtered out

What you need is `A !== B && A !== C`, which is evaluated like `(A !== B) && (A !== C)`
In this case the term will only be true id `option.text` is neither equal to `'Product Two'` nor to `'Product Three'`
So your term must be `option.text !== 'Product Two' && option.text !== 'Product Three'`

```js
console.clear()
menuOfProducts = [ 
  { text: 'Product One',
    selector: '#product-one #productone',
    path: 'productone' },
  { text: 'Product Two',
    selector: '#product-two #producttwo',
    path: 'shop/catalog/producttwo' },
  { text: 'Product Three',
    selector: '#product-three #productthree',
    path: 'shop/catalog/productthree' },
  { text: 'Product Four',
    selector: '#product-four #productfour',
    path: 'shop/catalog/productfour' },
  { text: 'Product Five',
    selector: '#product-five #productfive',
    path: 'shop/catalog/productfive' }
]

menuOfProducts = menuOfProducts.filter(function (option) {
  return option.text !== 'Product Two' &&  option.text !== 'Product Three';
});

console.log(menuOfProducts)
```

#### What is operator precedence

The MDN documentation says:

> Operator precedence determines the way in which operators are parsed with respect to each other. Operators with higher precedence become the operands of operators with lower precedence.

This means that we have a sorted list of all possible operators and the operators which are higher in this list are parsed before the lower ones.
We can visualize this with the use of parentheses [`(` and `)`] which are the Grouping operators and on top of the operator precedence list.

One example `A = B + C`
This is like `A = (B + C)`, because the Assignment operator (single `=`) has precedence 3 and the Addition operator (`+`) has precedence 13, hence being parsed before the `=`

Your term was `A !== B || C`.  Let's take a look at the precedence list

```
| precedence | operator name     | operator |
| 10         | Strict Inequality |   !==    |
|  5         | Logical OR        |   ||     |
```

The Strict Inequality operator has higher priority than the Logical OR operator. So `A !== B || C` is similar to `(A !== B) || C`
All the operators

Comment: Thanks very much for that explanation. Very useful indeed :) Thanks for your time in providing feeback. This coupled with the solutions suggested by others makes much more sense now.